# From ssh private EC2 im unable to connect to my aws RDS Postgres database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

after running the following command

```
docker run --rm \
    -it --name *****-db-setup \
    839*******.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/****-backend:dev-latest \
    bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate --trace
```

I get the error

```
** Invoke db:drop (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke db:check_protected_environments (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

any idea where this connection error could be coming from? also if I take out a line and just run

```
docker run --rm \
    -it --name ****-db-setup \
    839*****.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/****-backend:dev-latest
```

I get a 8 errors of

```
.env: line 1: $: command not found
.env: line 2: $: command not found
.env: line 3: $: command not found
.env: line 4: $: command not found
.env: line 5: $: command not found
.env: line 6: $: command not found
.env: line 7: $: command not found
.env: line 8: $: command not found
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_HOST") { "db" } %>
  username: <%= ENV.fetch("DB_USER") { "postgres" } %>
  port: <%= ENV["DB_PORT"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["DB_PASS"] %>
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: backend_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: backend_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV["DB_NAME"] %>

    enter code here
```

Comment: Is your rds in same subnet or VPC as the instance?

Comment: Can you add your `config/database.yml` to your question?

Comment: @Marcin yes its in the same VPC. as for subnets the RDS has two and the EC2/ECS has one all different, based on the architecture picture they are not supposed to be under the same subnet just VPC

Comment: @rmlockerd ive added it

Comment: It looks like you need to set `DB_HOST` in your environment to be your RDS endpoint (which should be something like `foo.something.region.rds.amazonaws.com`). The fallback in your `database.yml` is to use the host `db`, which is what's popping up in the connection error.

Comment: @rmlockerd I have an env file where its fetching the host and I defined the host as the end point there. Could it be that its not finding that env file with the defined variables? also do I have to docker compose up again if Im making changes to the database.yml?

Comment: If you change `database.yml`, yes you will need to update the image. I suggest checking that your `.env` file is getting loaded when you run the composer and that the `DB_HOST` and `DB_PORT` vars are getting passed to your rails app container (i.e., specified in your `docker-composer.yml`).

Comment: @rmlockerd  I have a s3 bucket for config variables, when I run its fetch command it returns the 5 variables I need with the correct values for DB_host and DB_PORT

Answer (score 0):

You can check few steps here to troubleshoot this,

1. Check our routing table to make sure you have routing in place correctly.
2. Check your security groups in both EC2 and RDS to make sure they allow relevant ports to the relevant sources.
3. Check your NACL (network ACL) list.

Comment: What should I be looking out for in the network ACLs?

Comment: just check the source ( this case IP address of EC2 ) is not denied to access the subnet of the RDS